# How can Splunk distinguish between output to stdout and stderr in Docker context?

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, splunk

We have a Java application that can be run in Docker containers. It produces messages to *stdout* and *stderr* with a different level of detail for different audiences.

Configuring Splunk as log driver all log lines received by Splunk a marked with source *stdout* although there must be log lines being logged to *stderr*.

Splunk log driver configuration in docker-compose:

```
logging:
    driver: splunk
    options:
        splunk-url: https://splunkhf:8088
        splunk-token: [TOKEN]
        splunk-index: splunk_index
        splunk-insecureskipverify: "true"
        splunk-sourcetype: log4j
        splunk-format: "json"
        tag: "{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}"
```

Example log message sent to splunk:

```
{
   line: 2021-01-12 11:37:49,191;10718;INFO ;[Thread-1];Logger; ;Executed all shutdown events. 
   source: stdout 
   tag: service_95f2bac29286/582385192fde 
}
```

How can I configure Docker or Splunk to differentiate correctly between those different streams?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the service from docker-compose without *-d* then the logs lose their original source. It seems that Docker and Docker-Compose put everything from the container's output streams to stdout and use stderr for their logs.

Using the *-d* flag the log messages do not lose their original output stream.